# Faster way of doing this?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code, but it runs the foreach loop one at a time. Is there a way of making them all run at once?

```
foreach($json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] as $header)
{
    $orders_array[] = $header;
    $guests_array[] = $header['guests']['cnr_output_guest_detail'];
    $items_array[] = $header['items']['cnr_output_item_detail'];
}   

foreach($guests_array as $guests)
{
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_guest_detail', (array)$guests);
}
foreach($items_array as $items)
{
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_item_detail', (array)$items);
}
foreach($orders_array as $orders)
{
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_ship_to_header', (array)$orders);
}
```

Comment: The indentation is deceptive.  There is no nesting happening here, just a set of `foreach` loops arranged in series.

Comment: Yup,There is no nesting, the indentation helps me group things quickly while coding. Since my coding is very messy. How would I nest these to do what I described?

Comment: How long does it take to execute now?  How long do you need it to execute in?  "Faster" is meaningless without specific goals.

Comment: I'm going through thousands if not millions of keys and values, every millisecond counts in the long run. I'll take any suggestions that improve the speed, if it's proven to execute faster.

Comment: Are you sure this is the slowest part of your code? If you're inserting multiple rows, use a multiple insert query (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not this:

```
foreach($json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] as $header) {
    //$orders_array[] = $header;
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_ship_to_header', (array)$header);
    //$guests_array[] = $header['guests']['cnr_output_guest_detail'];
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_guest_detail', (array)$header['guests']['cnr_output_guest_detail']);
    //$items_array[] = $header['items']['cnr_output_item_detail'];
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_item_detail', (array)$header['items']['cnr_output_item_detail']);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine

```
foreach ( $json['orders']['cnr_output_ship_to_header'] as $header ) {
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_guest_detail', (array)  $header['guests']['cnr_output_guest_detail']);
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_item_detail', (array) $header['items']['cnr_output_item_detail']);
    pdo_insert('cnr_output_ship_to_header', (array) $header);
}
```